Question about the "axis of evil"in cosmology and the Doppler effect due to the solar system's motion
The cosmic microwave background (CMB) can be described by its anisotropies in a direction $\hat{n}$ in the celestial sphere
$$
\delta T(\hat{n})=\frac{ T(\hat{n})-\bar{T}}{\bar{T}}
$$
where $\bar{T}$ is the average temperature of the CMB. The anisotropies can be decomposed in spherical harmonics
$$\delta T(\hat{n})=\sum_{lm} \delta T_{lm}Y_{lm}(\hat{n})$$
As I undertand it, in a true Gaussian distribution, the power $C_l$ for each mode $l$ should be randomly distributed among the $m$'s and reorienting the $\hat{z}$ axis of the spherical harmonics shouldn't change this. On the contrary, if we can find a specific axis $\hat{n}_l$ for which most of the power $C_l$ is concentrated in one mode $m$, then we have a prefered axis.
I think I understand that $\delta T_{00}$ gives the average strength of the anisotropies. Also, the dipole distribution with $l=1$ has a prefered axis which aligns with the motion of the solar system. This makes sense due to the Doppler effect: Photons coming from that direction will appear hotter, causing a dipolar distribition.
I also recall that the measurement of the speed of our solar system, calculated in this way, agrees with other calculations of it.
The next multipoles, $l=2$ and $l=3$ also seem to have a preferred axis, which seems to be the rotation axis of the solar system. First question:

I hear sometimes that this means that the CMB is slightly hotter on one side of the plane of the solar system and slightly colder on the other... Is this true? That might make sense for an octupole moment but I think that might be an oversimplification since the quadrupole moment has reflection symmetry along the equator (i.e. it has the same temperature on both poles) so it wouldn't cause an asymmetry of that kind. Also, I'm not sure what's the $m$ that receives most of he power when we use the rotation axis to align the spherical harmonics. If it were the $m=0$ I would understand the "hotter above and colder below" but for any $m\neq 0$ there will be extra information in the longitudinal anisotropies which wouldn't correspond to that simple picture.

My second question is:

Does the fact that the higher multipole momenta have a preferred axis "bleed" into the dipole moment? In other words, I'd expect the measurement of the solar system's speed based on the preferred axis of the dipole moment to be slightly wrong, since a bit of that preferred  axis might be due to the axis of evil and not just the movement of the solar system. Does this make any sense? Or is the solar system's speed measured with the CMB in "good" agreement with measurements done by other means?


The dipole component has 100 times more amplitude, so there could be errors at the $<1$% level.
